# Is there a good way to store a lot of small PDF files?

Tags: pdf, hdf5

The nature of my job requires me to make a lot of PDF images of data that I am analyzing. At the end of the day I only use maybe 10% of the images as a "proof" of concept but I still want to save all of the images in case people want to scrutinize my work.

I am thinking of something like, storing the PDF files in an hdf5 file but as far as I am aware this is not possible (my only interface with hdf5 files are through the h5py module in python).

Do you guys have any recommendation?

Comment: Asking for recommendations is specifically against community guidelines: "Seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more. This question is likely to lead to opinion-based answers."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to store (many) PDF files within an HDF5 file. One way to solve this could be to create a dataset for each PDF, and have the dataset be of data type opaque of one dimension with a size equal to the size of the PDF file. If you are not bound to a specific technology, you could solve your use-case using [HDFql](http://www.hdfql.com) as follows:

```python
# import HDFql package
import HDFql

# create an HDF5 file named 'pdf.h5' and use (i.e. open) it
HDFql.execute("CREATE AND USE FILE pdf.h5")

# get all files contained in root directory '/my_dir' which, for the sake
# of this example, contains the PDFs to store in the HDF5 file
HDFql.execute("SHOW FILE /my_dir/")

i = 0
while HDFql.cursor_next() == HDFql.SUCCESS:

    # get name of PDF file
    file_name = HDFql.cursor_get_char()

    # create dataset containing the content of the PDF file
    HDFql.execute("CREATE DATASET dset_%d VALUES FROM BINARY FILE \"/my_dir/%s\"" % (i, file_name))

    i += 1
```